# Rotate an object by exact transform degree when hover on a button

Tags: jquery, css, animation, rotation, transform

I want to create a menu whose arrow point always points at the button I hover cursor and if I don't hover on any then it stay on where I hovered last time.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first row">
      <button class="two btn btn-default col-xs-2  col-sm-offset-5   left">Second</button>
    </div>
    <div class="second row">
      <button class="one btn btn-default col-xs-2 col-sm-offset-2   left">First</button>
      <p class="col-xs-4 text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>  
      </p>
      <button class="three btn btn-default col-xs-2   left">Third</button>
    </div>
    <div class="third row">
      <button class="four btn btn-default col-xs-2  col-sm-offset-5   left">Fourth</button>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

SCSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 50px;
  .first {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .second {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .third {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
} 
}

.rotate-first{
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.rotate-second{
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.rotate-third{
   transform: rotate(180deg);
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.rotate-fourth{
   transform: rotate(270deg);
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("button.one").hover(function(){
    $("span").addClass("rotate-first");
});
$("button.two").hover(function(){
    $("span").addClass("rotate-second");
});
$("button.three").hover(function(){
    $("span").addClass("rotate-third");
});
$("button.four").hover(function(){
    $("span").addClass("rotate-fourth");
});
```

You can check the codes [here](https://codepen.io/petervatler/pen/dRRMYw).

Is it possible with CSS too? Or only JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You just need to remove the different rotation classes when you hover before adding the relevant one back. That way, only one of the four classes is applied at a time, and you don't get stuck.

```
$(function(){
  var spanClasses = 'rotate-first rotate-second rotate-third rotate-fourth';

  $("button.one").hover(function(){
      $("span").removeClass(spanClasses).addClass("rotate-first");
  });
  $("button.two").hover(function(){
      $("span").removeClass(spanClasses).addClass("rotate-second");
  });
  $("button.three").hover(function(){
      $("span").removeClass(spanClasses).addClass("rotate-third");
  });
  $("button.four").hover(function(){
      $("span").removeClass(spanClasses).addClass("rotate-fourth");
  });
});
```

As to whether this is possible with just CSS: No, not any way that I can think of. You could rotate the arrow on hover with CSS, but your arrow would snap back to wherever it is by default when you remove the hover. Toggling the classes through JavaScript as you are doing is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the removeClass() although I put it after the addClass() but it didn't work, bundling the classes into a variable is a very good idea!

Comment: No problem! Keep in mind that your operations are going to be done in order, left to right. So if you addClass and then removeClass afterwards, you're left with no classes! You could add one class and remove the other three in each function, making four unique functions (i.e., add A, remove BCD; add B, remove ACD; etc.), but easier to just remove them all and then add the one you want.